# Visual Studio 2017 HRESULT: 0x80070005 / E_ACCESSDENIED on project creation

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm running Visual Studio 2017, version 15.0.0+26228.9

[image]

When I'm trying to create a new project via *File > New > Project...* in Visual Studio 2017, I'm receiving the following error message and the project is not created:

> Access denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Don't mind the german message text in the screenshot:
[image: Exception message on project creation]

This happens for every project template I use (e.g. C# WPF, VB WPF, C# Console App...).

If I try to create a project via the quick search box on the starting page of visual studio, VS just crashes instantly with no exception message at all:

[image: Quick search project template box]

Has anybody else ran into this issue and might know how to fix it?

Comment: Resetting als settings to default didn't solve the problem.

Comment: After attempting a "Repair" installation, VS is now completely broken and crashes immediately after startup with an "unknown error". Seems like I've to do a complete uninstall and reinstall of all VS modules now. :-(

Comment: Same error here, if you get solution please share

Comment: I solved it reparing and rebooting

Comment: This happens after I installed .NET Core SDK 2.1, on *two* separate computers. So I think this might be related.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I had the same error.
I solved it by following the procedure :

- Shutdown all instances of Visual Studio
- Delete    %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_f4938f75\privateregistry.bin    file (the ID after 15.0_ may be different per machines)
- Start VS as    normal user

all credit for this should go to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31188/access-denied-error-1.html

Comment: In fact, this is the real solution - and a more precise one than my attempt to just install the program over and over again...

Comment: Be aware it will disable all your active extensions. Just need to go and re-enable them

Comment: Be aware that it will reset the entire environment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed it.
Long story short, the reason for the problem was an incomplete and/or corrupted setup.

But it was a rather bumpy road to the solution, including several un-installations and re-installations until I eventually figured out why the setup was indeed faulty.

Sometimes I got an exception during the installation, other times it finished just fine, but the HRESULT-error persisted when I tried to create a new project.

I my special case, this was caused by the corporate firewall, that blocked some of the setup packets from being downloaded by the web installer. I solved the issue by connecting to an open WiFi, that's not filtered by the firewall.

As I'm working with a standard user, UAC kicks in when I start any installation routine. When I first started the setup via UAC and connected to the free WiFi, it wasn't able to find the packet servers.
It took me a minute to realize that the admin user I used for UAC had his own internet proxy settings, that wouldn't work with the open WiFi.

After I logged on as administrator, disabled the proxy and logged on as my main user again, I ran the setup again - and it failed again with a bunch of "incomplete workload" messages. As frustrated as I was at this point, I simply ran it again via the "Change" button without even closing the webinstaller and this time it finally completed without any errors!

After this, I could start VS just normally and creation of a new project was possible.

So, if you experiencing any troubles like this, I would strongly recommend to run a "Repair" or "Change" installation just over your existing one but try to avoid any firewalls between you and the internet.

Answer (score 0):

1/ open control panel -> program and future - > IIS Express -> select Repair

2/ Refresh some time -> open Visual Studio

This 's about IIS Express in your computer . you only need to repair it in control panel is ok .

I tried and success.

Answer (score 0):

My solution,

The Clang-format caused this. just disable clang-format:

Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->General->Eable ClangFormat Support

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I tried to create a test certificate.
I have just launched VS as administrator.
And everything is Ok

Answer (score -1):

The below solution worked for me

- Make sure all the instances of Visual studio are closed.
- Go to `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_****`
- Delete the file `privateregistry.bin`

Answer (score -1):

I tried changing the version of .Net Framework from 4.0 to 3.5 while creating the project. This solved my error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LauzC.jpg)

[Changing version of Net Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LauzC.jpg)