# The file Resources.resx could not be found within the project templates, continuing to run, but the resulting project may not build properly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm running VS 2022 version 17.0_50c4cab0

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.3

Microsoft .Net Framework
Version 4.8

I got the error, '**Access denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**' when I try to create a new project via File > New > Project... in Visual Studio 2022, specifically, **WPF App (.Net Framework)** project and it got resolved by deleting the privateregistry.bin file.

but then getting the below error,

**The file Resources.resx could not be found within the project templates, continuing to run, but the resulting project may not build properly**

If I click Ok and continue, it gives another error,

**Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component**

I tried the following steps,

- Visual Studio Repair and Restart,
- Deleted the privateregistry.bin file from VS %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- Restarted the VS several times
- Reset all settings
- Ran Visual Studio as Administrator:

but still the error occurs.
Can someone help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a corruption in the installation or a permissions issue.
Here are a few steps you could try to resolve the issue:

Run Visual Studio as Administrator:
Right-click on the Visual Studio icon and select "Run as administrator." This ensures that Visual Studio has the necessary permissions to create and modify files.

Reset Visual Studio Settings:
Sometimes, corrupted settings can cause unexpected issues. You can try resetting Visual Studio settings to default. Go to "Tools" > "Import and Export Settings" > "Reset all settings."

Check .NET Framework Installation:
Ensure that your .NET Framework installation is correct. You can repair or reinstall the .NET Framework from the Control Panel.

Repair or Reinstall Visual Studio:
Since you've already tried repairing, consider uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio. Make sure to download the latest version from the official Microsoft website.

If you still have problems, you can refer to and try the solutions in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43182648/17960080).

Comment: I have tried all the options which you have also shared even uninstalled the Professional and installed Community version but still the error exists. Something got corrupted in my machine it seems. No luck :(

Comment: Hi,@Viji Priya. Is it possible to uninstall and reinstall to see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Hi @Hui Liu-MSFT,) I uninstalled and reinstalled the VS and before that I have deleted all the VS related folders from Program Files/Program Files (86) as well but still the issue exists. 
Not sure whether I'm missing to include any .NET Framework (version) component while installation to create 'WPF App (.Net Framework)'